# view from xib won't autoresize

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a custom split view controller, designed to work as much like apple's as possible.

I use this split view in three different places.  Two of these places, the master is a view simply a UIViewController with a UIView attached, and created programmatically.

The third example however is a UIViewController with a XIB.

The problem is that the first two split views adjust their widths correctly.  However the screen with the XIB does not.  I'm not doing anything fancy, just trying to set the content view of my master with a view that is passed in to it.  And setting the autoresizing masks as such:

```
    // create container views
    masterView = [[VS_MasterView alloc] init];
    masterView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, masterViewWidth, self.view.frame.size.height);
    masterView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:masterView];

    // get the views
    UIViewController *masterViewController = (UIViewController *)[_viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    UIViewController *detailViewController = (UIViewController *)[_viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    // set their bounds
    [masterViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:masterViewController];
    [masterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    masterViewController.view.frame = masterView.bounds;
    masterViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [masterView addSubview:masterViewController.view];
```

is there some sort of special case with XIB files and resizing them in this situation? I don't feel like there should be.

thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualising that, can you post a screenshot perhaps ? also, on the second line, when you set the frame for masterView, who is the self object, meaning where does this code run ?

Comment: there are 3 views in this custom split view.  the master (the panel on the left) the details (the larger view) and the third is the view that holds them both.  That is what 'self' is referring to.  As for a screenshot, it simply looks and acts exactly like a normal split view controller

Comment: Aha I see, did you try enabling the "Requires full screen" checkbox in the view's parameters ? (If you're using Storyboards)

if not, did you try manually setting the view's size in the size inspector ?

Comment: The code you show looks reasonable. Does the `masterViewController` override `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? If it does, is it doing anything special to its view, like setting  the `autoResizingMask`?

Comment: @Mostafa Torbjørn Berg the size inspector is greyed out and i cant adjust the width

Comment: @herzbube masterViewController does not override either of those methods, and i am hardcoding its width to 320

Comment: @JMD Then I'm sorry to say that I am out of ideas. I'm not a XIB expert, though...

Comment: Will you please attach a screen shot to understand that what the problem is actually?